# No-Cache set for jersey header response, but persisted data not returned

Tags: angularjs, caching, jersey, restangular

I have a jersey client returning json response.  I have quite crudely set a no-cache header in all my jersey responses.  However, when I am making changes, while I see the changes in the database...when I test the raw rest url, the data I have persisted isnt returned unless I restart the app server (Tomcat).

I have set no-cache using a ContainerResponseFilter.

```
public class HeaderResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
            MediaType type = response.getMediaType();
            if (type != null) {
                String contentType = type.toString();
                if (!contentType.contains("charset")) {
                    contentType = contentType + ";charset=utf-8";
                    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", contentType);
                    response.getHeaders().putSingle("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am seeing no-cache set as the header in chrome:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:1986
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 30 Sep 2014 20:22:02 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Restart the app server..and voila, there it is, as per persisted database record.

I am using angularjs with Restangular, and am not explicity setting any cache policy on the client via Angular/Restangular...wouldn't know how at the moment.

Its nothing to do with angular/restangular, as bypassing this and going directly to the rest endpoint, I don't see what is persisted in Oracle.  And its nothing to do with local caching in the browser, as when I try the raw URL in IE vs Chrome I can't see it either.

---Update---
have created an @NoCache annotation to try that approach, and in the client I am setting:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

But i can't disable caching!! Help....

Any help appreciated.

Regards

i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was caching in my JPA layer....

Only a small app, so am disabling the EclipseLink shared cache...and now it is working.

```
<persistence-unit name="xp-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">        
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```